# RSSI signal from cellular network to be obtained in android application

Tags: android, eclipse, location, gsm, rssi

I am a beginner in android developing and I am working on a project to create an app to locate cell phones without using GPS.Can anybody help me with how to get the RSSI for GSM and the distance if possible.Any code available for this purpose would be appreciated really.
I would also like to know, what other information can we get from the SIM card.

Answer (score 0):

For SIM information including RSSI, you need to look at the [Android Telephony](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/package-summary.html) and related APIs.

You can't get the distance from the base station though.  You can get the [Cell Id](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellIdentityGsm.html), which gives you a rough location if matched up to a database.  Cell Id information is proprietary though, and publically available databases aren't always that accurate.  Or you could use three Cell Ids + RSSIs to do a rough triangulation calculation yourself.  The disadvantages with that are that many devices won't return cell info for the surrounding cells; you still need access to a reliable database of cell locations; ideally you should also include known WiFi hotspots; it's a lot of work to implement something that Android has already done.

Android handles location via its own [location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/package-summary.html) and [location services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) APIs.  [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) lets you choose the desired technology, e.g.NETWORK_PROVIDER or GPS_PROVIDER.  So you could just choose not to use GPS, and let Android give you the best available result from the network.

Comment: By any chance you happen to find the basic code needed to find the RSSI in dbm of GSM ?